# Determine number of divisors of $x^n -1$ of degree $k$. Why are they such a number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, finite-fields, coding-theory

Let us consider the codes $C[n,k]$ where $n=31$ and $k=5$ and base field $\mathbb{F}_2$. I know there are ${31}\choose{k}$ divisors of $x^ {31}-1$ of degree $k$. But I can't understand why. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Assuming that you mean $x^{31} - 1$ as a polynomial over $\mathbf{F}_2$, do you know how to factor it into linear factors?

Comment: Be careful!  $x^{31}-1$ has $\binom{31}k$ divisors of degree $k$ over $\mathbb{F}_{32}$, not $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph yes, I know the 2 cyclo cosets modulo 31. How can I conclude?

Comment: You are probably concentrating on *cyclic* codes :-)

Comment: And, what user10354138 said. Over $\Bbb{F}_2$ the polynomial $x^{31}-1$ has a single linear factor, no factors of degrees 2,3,4, six factors of degrees 5 and 6, none of degrees 7,8,9, fifteen of degree 10 etc.

Answer (score 0):

The field extension $_{32} / _2$ can be built as the smallest splitting field of $x^{32}-x$ (it is the standard proof of existence for a field of order $p^m$). So $x^{31}-1 = (x-α_1)...(x-α_{31})$ with $_{32} - \{0\} = \{α_1,...,α_{31}\}$, and any divisor of $x^{31}-1$ of degree $k$ can be obtained by selecting $k$ factors from $(x-α_1)...(x-α_{31})$ (order of selection irrelevant).

Comment: Ok, and hence the number of divisors of $x^{31} - 1$ of degree $31-k$ are exactly ${31}\choose{31-k}$, right?